# Expressing time derivatives of unit vectors as cross products: validity in any reference frame

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, classical-mechanics, cross-product

### Preamble

In angular dynamics, it is customary to describe the rotation of a rigid object  with the rotation of a reference frame attached to it, say having basis $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ as unit vector of the coordinate axes. The angular velocity is the rate at which the unit vectors rotate in space. I restrict myself to orthonormal, 'right-handed' coordinate systems.

I came across an approach that I found elegant in which the angular velocity of this frame $\vec{\omega}$ is *defined* as
$$ \omega_a = \frac{d\vec{b}}{dt} \cdot \vec{c},\quad  \omega_b = \frac{d\vec{c}}{dt} \cdot \vec{a}, \quad  \omega_c = \frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} \cdot \vec{b}$$
Given a vector with constant lenght but variable direction, the following is always a true construction
$$ \frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} = 
\underbrace{\left(\frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} \cdot \vec{a} \right)}_{\textrm{perpendicular, hence 0}} \vec{a}
+
\left(\frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} \cdot \vec{b} \right) \vec{b}
+
\left(\frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} \cdot \vec{c} \right) \vec{c}
$$
Since the condition of perpendicularity $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$ also leads to
$$
\frac{d\,}{dt} \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0 =
\frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} \cdot \vec{b} + \frac{d\vec{b}}{dt} \cdot \vec{a}
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\omega_c = - \frac{d\vec{b}}{dt} \cdot \vec{a}
$$
and since the like holds for $\frac{d\vec{b}}{dt}$, $\frac{d\vec{c}}{dt}$, $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}$,  $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{a}$, after a little playing around one gets
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{a}}{dt} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{a} \\
\frac{d\vec{b}}{dt} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{b} \\
\frac{d\vec{c}}{dt} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{c}
\end{equation}

This demonstration partly uses the fact that in the basis $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$, where the reasoning is being developed, it obviously holds $\vec{a}=(1,0,0)$, $\vec{b}=(0,1,0)$, $\vec{c}=(0,0,1)$.

### Intuition

It seems clear to me that the expressions of the time derivatives as cross products must hold when the operands are expressed in any arbitrary basis.
Note that I am still referring to the *rotating motion of that same reference frame $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$*. However, the vectors $\vec{\omega},\vec{a},\ldots$ may well be expressed in any other reference frame than $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$.
The two concepts --- a reference frame that moves and eventually describes motion of objects in that frame, and a reference frame that describes the vectors --- are conceptually quite different, I believe, although they might coincide.

If this intuition is right, there is the matrix $R$ that rotates the vectors in the old basis $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ into the new basis, say, $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$. Therefore, the following relationships should also hold:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dR\vec{a}}{dt} = R\vec{\omega} \times R\vec{a} \\
\frac{dR\vec{b}}{dt} = R\vec{\omega} \times R\vec{b} \\
\frac{dR\vec{c}}{dt} = R\vec{\omega} \times R\vec{c}
\end{equation}
but I kind of get stuck in a brute-force approach that turns out to be unwieldy all too soon.

### Question

Is there an elegant way in linear algebra that shows that expressing the rate of change of the unit vector by means of a cross product with the angular velocity of the frame it belongs to, holds for any reference frame you describe the chosen vectors with?

Correction to faults and flaws welcome.

Comment: Did you mean to use that $(Au×Av)⋅Aw=\det(Au,Av,Aw)=\det(A)(u×v)⋅w$ so that $A^T(Au×Av)=\det(A)(u×v)$ which simplifies further if $A\in SO(3)$?

Comment: @LutzL I can indeed see the steps of your reasoning and their relevance; thanks. Would you be willing to convert it into a fully-fledged answer, perhaps referring to the same symbology, for the benefit of future readers? Please also note that the handling of the left-hand side with the time derivative could be included for completeness.

Comment: When you write “any reference frame,” it looks like you mean to restrict this to orthonormal coordinate systems, most likely all with the same chirality. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: @amd Correct. I will edit the post.

Comment: Did you know beforehand Darboux vector formulation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_vector) which is knowm to be an intrinsic concept, i.e. base-independent ?